# Gatling and XPath problems

Tags: xpath, gatling

Using IntelliJ and a xml soap response, I get a xpath generated that is unique using IntelliJs built in functionality.

Putting this into gatling scala script

```
val scn = scenario("RuleEngineSimulation")
    .exec(http("request_0")
        .post("/EngasjementBasisA2A")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .body(RawFileBody("RuleEngineSimulation_request.xml"))
        .basicAuth("test234","test234")
        .check(xpath("/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/e:HentRisikoOversiktResponse/ef:engasjementOversiktRisikoer/ef:risikogrupper/ef:risikogruppe/ef:risikoer/ef:risiko/ef:partref/text()").saveAs("partref")))
```

Running this gives me the following:

Namespace prefix 'SOAP-ENV' has not been declared

Please advice.

Thanks

Magnus

Comment: You need to create a namespaceBinding to tell the processor what namespace to use for the "SOAP-ENV" prefix (and the `e`, `ef` namespace-prefixes). Otherwise, they are kind of like variables with a null pointer and it doesn't know how to interpret your XPath statement.